# How to display Yes/No instead of True/False for bool? in c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

I get the error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'.  How do I return 'Yes' or 'No' instead of true/false?

```
public bool? BuyerSampleSent
{
    get { bool result;
          Boolean.TryParse(this.repository.BuyerSampleSent.ToString(), out result);
        return result ? "Yes" : "No";
    }
    set { this.repository.BuyerSampleSent = value; }
}
```

Comment: Your type should be string instead of bool, if you want to display a string.

Comment: SO has a [code](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) formater to include codes in posts.

Comment: I've also edited your question to include the actual code and not a picture of it.

Comment: You cannot have a variable that has 2 types like string and bool

Comment: TryParse requires a bool argument, which is why I declared result as bool.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't *return* a string if the return type is `bool` (or `bool?` in this case).  You return a `bool`:

```
return result;
```

Notice, however, that you ask...

> How to *display* Yes/No...

This code isn't *displaying* anything.  This is a property on an object, not a UI component.  In the UI you can display whatever you like using this property as a flag:

```
someObject.BuyerSampleSent ? "Yes" : "No"
```

Conversely, if you want a display-friendly message on the object itself (perhaps it's a view model?) then you can add a property for that message:

```
public string BuyerSampleSentMessage
{
    get { return this.BuyerSampleSent ? "Yes" : "No"; }
}
```

Comment: OK, I see your point.  I added a property using your suggestion:         public string BuyerSampleSentMessage
        {
            get
            {
                bool result;
                Boolean.TryParse(this.BuyerSampleSent.ToString(), out result);
                
                return result ? "Yes" : "No"; 
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

Your method returns a bool as @Pierre-Luc points out.  You need to change that to a String.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return a bool value "Yes" or "No". In C#, **bool** is a keyword for Boolean Data Type.You cannot override this behavior of a keyword.
Read more about C# Boolean Data Type [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8f5xwh7.aspx).

In your case you can do the following:

```
public string BuyerSampleSent
{
    get
    {
        string result= "No";
        if (this.repository.BuyerSampleSent.Equals("true",StringComparisson.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) // <-- Performance here
            result = "Yes";
        return result;
    }
    set
    {
        this.repository.BuyerSampleSent = value;
    }
}
```