# display yes / no instead of bool true false in results C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, boolean

I have been trying to figure out how to display yes / no instead of a bool result of true / false to make this easier to read for my users.

I am using c# and visual studio 2015 and I have taken a look and try to apply some of the techniques noted here in stackoverflow 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22540308/how-to-display-yes-no-instead-of-true-false-for-bool-in-c-sharp) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20338154/mvc-model-boolean-display-yes-or-no).

Im not to sure which is the best way to resolve the query that I have.  In a nutshell I have a database table that holds 3 columns with bit datatypes (eg. A, B & C).  This table is the fed through the use of entity framework to my MVC project.

The model associated with this table holds these columns as bool.  I an using this table to list items in the database, however the results for these items display True / False to the user (see image below).

[image: Screen Shot of results]

I have tried to change my Razor code to complete this task but have failed.

```
@item.AttachmentA.isTrue?"Yes":"No")
```

And I have also tried this,

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AttachmentA.isTrue?"Yes":"No")
```

For both above, I'm getting compilation error that states,

> 'System.Nullable' does not contain a definition for 'isTrue' and no extension method 'isTrue' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Nullable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I cant quite seem to get the above working.  Would I be able to complete an if statement in my controller to complete this?

I have tried to complete this with something like the following code but this doesn't seem to work.

```
// GET: View for ACTIVE items and set status of the bool for true / false
public ActionResult Active()
{
    List<vwStatusActive> clientRecordsActive = db.vwStatusActives.ToList();

    foreach (vwStatusActive active in clientRecordsActive)
    {
        if (vwStatusActive == true)
        {
            vwStatusActive = 'Yes';
        }
        else
        {
            vwStatusActive = 'No';
        }
    }

    return View(clientRecordsActive);
}
```

I have changed the above if statement in the controller to now hold variables for the bool true / false.

```
      // GET: View for ACTIVE items and set status of the bool for true / false
    public ActionResult Active()
    {
        List<vwStatusActive> clientRecordsActive = db.vwStatusActives.ToList();


        bool t = true;
        bool f = false;

        foreach (vwStatusActive active in clientRecordsActive)
        {
            if (t == true)
            {
                t = "Yes";
            }
            else
            {
                t = "No";
            }

        }

        return View(clientRecordsActive);
    }
```

I now however get two error for the string items "Yes", "No" that state,

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool

If anyone has any suggestions on best practices, can you please advise?

Comment: Hi! Please can you edit your question replacing 'doesn't work' with actual compiler errors / runtime errors. Thanks!

Comment: You are trying to assign values to a type. Anyway a bit more code and errors would help to focus on the issue. Where are the variables that store the rendered string?

Comment: See example here for changing the dropwdown's display value: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517695/1489570

Comment: You missed start bracket and @ in yur code. 
Do like this and let me know. **@(item.AttachmentA.isTrue?"Yes":"No")**

Comment: What is `vwStatusActive`? You are using it as a Type (`List<vwStatusActive>`), then test it against a `bool` and then try to assign a `string` value.

Comment: In your Active Action method, you need to write like this,                        
         `if (vwStatusActive == true)
            {
                active.vwStatusActive = 'Yes';
            }` You missed **active.**

Comment: The message about `item.AttachmentA.isTrue` says that (the Type of) "AttachmentA" (which apparently is some Nullable type) doesn't have an "isTrue" property. You might need `item.AttachmentA.Value.isTrue` (but this will fail if AttachmentA is null).

Comment: @BasantaMatia many thanks, I have made the change for the empty bracket but this doesn't resolve the problem. I get the following error message 'bool' does not contain a definition for 'isTrue' and no extension method 'isTrue' accepting a first argument of type 'bool' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @HansKesting many thanks, I have  added the additional .Value attribute but this doesn't resolve the problem. I get the following error message 'bool' does not contain a definition for 'isTrue' and no extension method 'isTrue' accepting a first argument of type 'bool' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @HansKesting vwStatusActive is a view model that lists all my properties for that item.   The data is pulled in fine by using the code line: List<vwStatusActive> clientRecordsActive = db.vwStatusActives.ToList();   However I thought that if I can note complete this task using Razor, I could maybe pull the list of items back in the controller and then use a foreach loop to loop through the records and display any true status to yes and any false to no.

Answer (score 2):

**If AttachmentA property is of type bool then use**

@(item.AttachmentA ? "Yes":"No")

OR

@{var isAttachmentA = (item.AttachmentA  ? "Yes" : "No");}
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => isAttachmentA )

**If AttachmentA property is of type bool? (Nullable bool) then use**

@(item.AttachmentA.GetValueOrDefault() ? "Yes":"No")

OR

@{var isAttachmentA = (item.AttachmentA.GetValueOrDefault()  ? "Yes" : "No");}
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => isAttachmentA )